# python pandas unbound local error while calling a function 'df.apply'

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to use df.apply() function in pandas but getting the following error. The function is trying to convert every entry into 0 if it is less than 'threshold'

```
from pandas import * 
import numpy as np
def discardValueLessThan(x, threshold):
    if x < threshold : return 0
    else: return x

df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

>>> df
          A         B         C
0 -1.389871  1.362458  1.531723
1 -1.200067 -1.114360 -0.020958
2 -0.064653  0.426051  1.856164
3  1.103067  0.194196  0.077709
4  2.675069 -0.848347  0.152521
5 -0.773200 -0.712175 -0.022908
6 -0.796237  0.016256  0.390068
7 -0.413894  0.190118 -0.521194

df.apply(discardValueLessThan, 0.1)

>>> df.apply(discardValueLessThan, 0.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.8.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3576, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.8.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3637, in _apply_standard
    e.args = e.args + ('occurred at index %s' % str(k),)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message looks like a `pandas` bug to me, but I think there are two other problems.

First, I think you have to either specify named parameters or use `args` to pass additional arguments to `apply`.  Your second argument is probably being interpreted as an axis.  But if you use

```
df.apply(discardValueLessThan, args=(0.1,))
```

or

```
df.apply(discardValueLessThan, threshold=0.1)
```

then you'll get

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index A')
```

because `apply` doesn't act elementwise, it acts on entire Series objects.  Other approaches include using `applymap` or boolean indexing, i.e.

```
In [47]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
          A         B         C
0 -0.135336 -0.274687  1.480949
1 -1.079800 -0.618610 -0.321235
2 -0.610420 -0.422112  0.102703

In [49]: df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: discardValueLessThan(x, 0.1))

In [50]: df1
Out[50]: 
   A  B         C
0  0  0  1.480949
1  0  0  0.000000
2  0  0  0.102703
```

or simply

```
In [51]: df[df < 0.1] = 0

In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
   A  B         C
0  0  0  1.480949
1  0  0  0.000000
2  0  0  0.102703
```

Comment: axis is the second parameter so 0.1 is indeed being interpreted as the axis. I just pushed to master a more informative error message if axis is not 0 or 1.

Comment: @ChangShe: yeah, the bug I was thinking of is that someone was trying to catch the NameError when that wasn't the exception that would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this:

`df.apply(discardValueLessThan, args=(0.1,))`

The way you're doing it the 0.1 is not passed as the argument to discardValueLessThan.